# w3m Always Display Link Numbers

Tags: w3m

I can turn on link numbering with L f, but how can I keep link numbering always on?;)

I'm not sure if emacs-w3m picks up config from ~/.w3m/w3m, cause I do find a "display_link_number 1" there, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

L f is bound to:

```
L f runs the command w3m-lnum-follow (found in w3m-mode-map), which is
an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘w3m-lnum.el’.

It is bound to L f.

(w3m-lnum-follow ARG)

Turn on link numbers, ask for one and execute appropriate action on it.
If link - visit it, when button - press, when input - activate it,
If image - toggle it.
With prefix ARG visit link in new session or don’t move over
field/button/image on activation/push/toggle.
With ‘-’ ARG, for link image - go to it and toggle it, if link,
visit in background.  With -4 ARG, for link image - toggle it.
With double prefix ARG, prompt for url to visit.
With triple prefix ARG, prompt for url to visit in new session.
```

Comment: Are you talking about `emacs-w3m` or the command line `w3m` browser? If the latter, this is not the proper place to ask the question. Probably the Unix and Linux SE would be a better place.

Comment: I'm talking about emacs-w3m

Comment: Not sure what you mean, L f is defined in emacs-w3m directly. This prints a number next to every link.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was using a long-obsolete version of `w3m`. I cleaned it up and reinstalled from MELPA and I can now see the `L f` binding.

Comment: Sure, but this *.el file doesn't include a way to enable link-numbering always?;)

Comment: I haven't had time to check and all my attempts to use it have come up with nothing: I get errors so it's probably the case that I have misconfigured it, but I have not been able to sit down and  debug it.

Comment: Is it possible that I can just run (w3m-elnum-follow) whenever a w3m buffer opens, maybe?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm thinking wrong, cause enabling it always will probably conflict;) In other browsers, I have it bound to "f", so I'll try to that here, aswell;)